# Alternation group with two alternatives matching entire string

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, regex-alternation

I working on a regular expression which returns 1 only in case given value is A or B.

I used

```
select 'A' REGEXP '^A|B$'
```

The '|' symbol is behaving like "or", but the result is not as expected with AB:

```
select 'AB' REGEXP '^A|B$' = 1
```

while I expect no match here.

Comment: to clarify your question, please show examples of input that matches and input that doesn't match

Comment: `'AB'` matches both `^A` and `B$`.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current solution matches

- `^A` - `A` at the start of the string
- `|` - or
- `B$` - `B` at the end of the string.

The [**`REGEXP` operator**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) can return *partial* matches (unlike `LIKE`  operator that requires the wildcard pattern to match the whole string), and thus can match `ABC` and `CAB`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pLJ4SG/1/).

You may use

```
select 'A' REGEXP '^(A|B)$'
```

The `A|B` is inside a grouping construct here and `^` and `$` both modify the `A` and `B` branch. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pLJ4SG/2).

If these `A` and `B` are single chars, use a `[AB]` bracket expression:

```
'^[AB]$'
```

where `[AB]` matches `A` or `B`, and the `^` / `$` anchors modify each letter inside the brackets.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oQZM8m/1).